# Typical first-day change in specific gravity

Tags: specific-gravity

I recently started my first BIAB all-grain brew, but unfortunately my hydrometer broke before I could get an OG reading. I was targeting around a 1.065. Just around 24 hours later I took a reading and got a 1.030.

I also accidentally overpitched the yeast somewhat significantly (~1/3 packet of Safale US-05 for a 1 gallon brew).

I understand there's really no way to know for sure what the OG was, but I'm interested in knowing by roughly how much I undershot the mark.

Comment: If you add a list of the fermentables, we could make an estimate of the OG.  I'm don't know of a method to estimate based on the 24-hour gravity.

Comment: Just a FYI that is not an over-pitch of yeast. You could pitch 5 packs of safale 05 in a 1 gallon brew and it would still not be near overpitching :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one blunt but true answer: It's too late. There's no accurate way to know what the OG was.

Comment: True, you can only estimated it based on the ingredients, which is not always accurate either.